# how to set "any string" as a regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this condition

```
if(url.startswith("http://country.domain.com/motors/used-cars/") and (url!="http://country.domain.com/motors/used-cars/")):
    if url.startswith("http://country.domain.com/motors/used-cars/?page="):
        return None
    else:
        return url
```

It was working, but for some reasons, the company changed the url from:

```
http://country.domain
```

to

```
http://city.domain
```

and because there are many cities. I have many urls like these:

```
http://city1.domain
http://city2.domain
http://city3.domain
http://city4.domain
http://city20.domain
```

Back to my condition, I have to change it to add the `20` cities.

#### My question

Is there a way so I do this:

http://**whateverthenamehere**.doman

I guess regular expression on python is what I need but I couldn't know exactly what is the correct code

I tried using \s, \s* and \s+ but nothing work

could you help

Comment: Assuming city names are alphabetic, `http://[a-zA-Z]+\.domain` might do the trick.

Comment: @thg435 no that didn't work. the condition still always go to false

Comment: I love these "it doesn't work" comments. It sure as hell does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression to test that the URL starts with your path and variable first domain part, *plus more text*:

```
import re

match = re.search(r'^http://[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.domain.com/motors/used-cars/(.+)', url)
if match:
    if match.group(1).startswith('?page='):
        return None
    return url
```

The `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` character group matches all valid domain name characters; `\w` is not enough as it allows for underscores (`_`), not dashes (`-`).

The rest of the URL is captured in group 1, so you can inspect it further.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> # Not enough text in the URL:
... 
>>> re.search(r'^http://[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.domain.com/motors/used-cars/(.+)', 
...           'http://city42.domain.com/motors/used-cars/') is None
True
>>> # Remainder of the URL is captured for inspection:
...
>>> re.search(r'^http://[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.domain.com/motors/used-cars/(.+)',
              'http://city42.domain.com/motors/used-cars/?page=')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100621558>
>>> re.search(r'^http://[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.domain.com/motors/used-cars/(.+)',
              'http://city42.domain.com/motors/used-cars/?page=').group(1)
'?page='
>>> # specific URL mentioned in the comments:
...
>>> re.search(r'^http://[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.domain.com/motors/used-cars/(.+)',
              'http://testes.domain.com/motors/used-cars/jeep/wrangler/2014/6/5/jeep-wrangler-‌​2/?back=dWFlLmR1Yml6emxlLmNvbS9tb3RvcnMvdXNlZC1jYXJzLz9wYWdlPTM%3D&pos=8').group(1)
'jeep/wrangler/2014/6/5/jeep-wrangler-\xe2\x80\x8c\xe2\x80\x8b2/?back=dWFlLmR1Yml6emxlLmNvbS9tb3RvcnMvdXNlZC1jYXJzLz9wYWdlPTM%3D&pos=8'
```

Comment: do you mean import re?

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo: Hmm? What? *innocent whistle*.

Comment: but I have two conditions in the first `if`, you have one

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: *I combined them*. This is why the regular expression ends in `.+`.

Comment: still not working. for example `http://testes.domain.com/motors/used-cars/jeep/wrangler/2014/6/5/jeep-wrangler-2/?back=dWFlLmR1Yml6emxlLmNvbS9tb3RvcnMvdXNlZC1jYXJzLz9wYWdlPTM%3D&pos=8` still go to the `false` but it should go to `return ULR`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: No, that URL works correctly for me.

Comment: maybe because I forget to replace the `domain` with the real domain :P I am trying it